# Search documents in lucene that do not contain a field

Tags: java, lucene

I need to search only documents that do *not* contain a particular field.

I tried this, doesn't work:

```
BooleanQuery constrainedQuery = new BooleanQuery();
constrainedQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
constrainedQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("fieldName")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
```

Not sure if I can use QueryWrapperFilter for this either.
My current alternative is to search for everything and ignore the documents that contain the field in the hits. Looking for a better way, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FieldValueFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldValueFilter.html), with the negate flag.